# Should i index fields which have one of these two options: unsigned, unique (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Please see the code below to understand my question

```
CREATE TABLE seller (
            `id`  INT(11)   NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `status`            INT(11)    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            `phone`     VARCHAR(20)     UNIQUE NOT NULL,

            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
            KEY `phone` (`phone`),
            KEY `status` (`status`)
)
```

is that right I added these 
KEY `phone` (`phone`),
KEY `status` (`status`) lines to the end of the code?

Comment: How you index your table depends on the types of queries you plan to run.  Tell us how you plan to query with this table.

Answer (score 0):

`UNSIGNED` and `UNIQUE` are unrelated attributes.

`UNSIGNED` means that you will only put non-negative numbers in that field.  This is the case for *most* things that get stored in databases -- counters, lengths, etc.  `INT SIGNED` gives you a range of about +/- 2 billion.  `INT UNSIGNED` can hold 0 to about 4 billion.

`UNIQUE` implies two things:  a "uniqueness constraint" and an "index".

If you insert a row with the identical value for that column, the `INSERT` will get an error because you have violated the "uniqueness constraint".  You use such to catch programming errors.  If you have a table with one row per widget, it is handy to get an error if you attempt to insert a second row for the identical widget.

An `INDEX` is the key tool for making a database perform faster.  It provides a fast way to look up a widget by its "id".

While I am at it, let's discuss `NULL` vs `NOT NULL`.  Think of `NULL` as an 'extra value' for a column.  It could mean "not yet set", "unknown value", or any of several other things, based on your business logic.  On the other hand, *usually* a column must be supplied (again, based on business logic), so you usually want to declare the column to be `NOT NULL`.

There can (and should) be exactly one `PRIMARY KEY` for a table.  It uniquely identifies each row.

A `PRIMARY KEY` *is a* `UNIQUE` key *is a* `INDEX` (aka `KEY`).  All of those are structured as `BTrees` (in MySQL).

Back to your question:

> is that right I added these KEY phone (phone), KEY status (status) lines to the end of the code?

The syntax is correct.  Their usefulness is debatable.  If you never say `WHERE phone = '...'`, then `KEY(phone)` is useless.  Having it does no harm (other than wasting disk space and slowing down `INSERTs` a tiny amount).